# Prepaid SIM card for 1 month stay in Texas / USA

Tags: usa, cellphones, texas

I will be staying in Houston (Texas) for about a month and I'm looking for a prepaid SIM card that I can use during that time, preferably with mobile data.

**Update (more details):**

Primarily, I'm looking for data transfer. Voice calls are secondary, in fact, I could do without. I will be staying at the same hotel throughout the duration, so if the coverage area includes Houston that's good enough.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What are you looking for? A cheap Sim Card or one with a better coverage? Do you intend to use primarily for data trasnfer or voice calls? Have you looked at any carrier already?

Comment: If you are a UK resident you can use the "Three" provider to obtain the same rates in the US as you do in the UK.

Comment: How much data do you expect to use? Keep in mind that the hotel will probably have free Wi-Fi.

Comment: Did you take a look at this question: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/798/in-the-us-whats-a-good-prepaid-gsm-sim-card-without-a-phone

Comment: @gmauch: Thanks, I guess my question can be closed as duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most recent time I did this I got a 1-month prepaid SIM card from T-Mobile. I think was something like $70 with tax and a SIM card to fit my phone. There was a couple G of LTE data and some phone time. Pretty painless- maybe 5 minutes in the shop. [Here](http://prepaid-phones.t-mobile.com/prepaid-plans) are their current rates. It worked out okay, but coverage was a bit spotty outside major cities. 
The data is 'unlimited' but throttled back to 3G speed over the total data limit.

AT&T has similar plans, however the T-Mobile prepaid plan allowed tethering, which was a requirement for me (that's when you link your laptop with your cell phone and use the cell phone's mobile data connection to allow your laptop to access the internet). AT&T required a contract for that feature.